# Alter timeout vs improve coding Sql .view server timeout in a query with a big data table

Tags: sql, sql-server, timeout

I have a table in my databse that contains tens of millions of lines of `Payments` and `Transactions`.

- `Transactions` are grouped by `Period`
- `Periods` can have several `Transaction`, and there can be several `Periods` in one day.

My query code is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    lastTrx.[Num_TPA]
    , lastTrx.periodo_max
    , lastTrx.Transacao_max
    , firstTrx.Transacao_min
    , lastTrx.Data_Hora_Ficheiro_fim
    , firstTrx.Data_Hora_Ficheiro_ini
    , DATEDIFF(Minute, firstTrx.Data_Hora_Ficheiro_ini, lastTrx.Data_Hora_Ficheiro_fim) "minutos_periodo"
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            [Num_TPA]
            , SUBSTRING(REPLACE(STR([Num_Per_Trx_msg_Ult_Trn], 9), SPACE(1), '0'), 1, 3) AS [periodo_max]
            , MAX(SUBSTRING(replace(str([Num_Per_Trx_msg_Ult_Trn], 9), SPACE(1), '0'), 4, 3)) [Transacao_max]
            , MAX([Data_Hora_Ficheiro]) AS [Data_Hora_Ficheiro_fim]
        FROM 
            [GPOS].[dbo].[Data_PRD_VALUES_CUBO_LIGHT]
        GROUP BY 
            [Num_TPA]
            , SUBSTRING(REPLACE(STR([Num_Per_Trx_msg_Ult_Trn], 9), SPACE(1), '0'), 1, 3)
    ) AS lastTrx
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            [Num_TPA]
            , SUBSTRING(REPLACE(STR([Num_Per_Trx_msg_Ult_Trn], 9), SPACE(1), '0'), 1, 3) AS [periodo]
            , MIN(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(STR([Num_Per_Trx_msg_Ult_Trn], 9), SPACE(1), '0'), 4, 3)) AS [Transacao_min]
            , MIN([Data_Hora_Ficheiro]) AS [Data_Hora_Ficheiro_ini]
        FROM 
            [GPOS].[dbo].[Data_PRD_VALUES_CUBO_LIGHT]
        GROUP BY 
            [Num_TPA]
            , SUBSTRING(REPLACE(STR([Num_Per_Trx_msg_Ult_Trn], 9), SPACE(1), '0'), 1, 3)
    ) AS firstTrx ON lastTrx.Num_TPA = firstTrx.Num_TPA
WHERE 
    lastTrx.periodo_max = firstTrx.periodo
    AND lastTrx.Data_Hora_Ficheiro_fim != firstTrx.Data_Hora_Ficheiro_ini
ORDER BY 
    Num_TPA
    , periodo
```

The query above takes 40 seconds to run, which is too long.

When I put my query into a View it cannot run due to a time-out.

The intended result is for each terminal to have a statistic of the first and last transaction of each period and the number of minutes between each one.

Please help me to figure how to:

- Alter the timeout
- Make my query run faster

Comment: Increasing timeout it's just a way to avoid the issue / slow query. The issue is going to remain for a long time if it's not solved properly and it'll be bigger if this query will be executed by two or more connections.